# Remote Settings file

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# project and I would like store the admin's settings in a Settings file (not app.config), I'm wondering if this Settings file can be stored in a remote location like a server database or another computer in the same LAN, this would actually be the best thing because I want to push the admin's settings to all computers so a single file would be essential.  Is this even possible?  If it is, could someone please point me in the right direction (tuto, link, documentation, etc) on how to create a Settings file and how to establish a remote connection to it.

I thought about using a database but I don't see the convenience in using it just to store settings.  What do you guys think/suggest??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of a remote application settings file in Visual Studio / .NET.  However, there are many ways you could store and consume remote settings, either via a file or database.

A few questions you need to ask yourself is this....

Is it on a Local Network and will it only be consumed by Client software on the Local Network?  This would be the case if you were writing Intranet applications on a Corporate Network, for instance.

If so, then you can use a Shared Drive to host the file, and read it from any client with the same exact file path.

If you are going to consume it across the internet, you could create some type of service which returns a file when called.  Something like a Web service if it's being served from a Web Server like Apache or IIS.

If its going across the internet though, I would just recommend using a database.  Just because it's already set up to consume data across the net, and your record is just a data structure, it can be stored in either a file with x number of fields or a database table record having x fields with the same amount of effort.

---

### Sample Code for Custom Config File

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestAsync.Services
{
    public static class AppSettings
    {
        public static string SettingsFileLocation {get; set;}

        public static string Setting1 { get; set; }
        public static string Setting2 { get; set; }
        public static DateTime Setting3 { get; set; }

        static AppSettings()
        {           
            SettingsFileLocation = @"C:\Wherever\Whatever.config";
            LoadConfiguration();
        }

        public static void LoadConfiguration()
        {
           using(var fs = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(SettingsFileLocation)))
           {
               Setting1 = fs.ReadLine();
               Setting2 = fs.ReadLine();
               Setting3 = DateTime.Parse(fs.ReadLine());
               fs.Close();
           }

        }

        public static void SaveConfiguration()
        {
            using (var fs = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(SettingsFileLocation)))
            {
                fs.WriteLine(Setting1);
                fs.WriteLine(Setting2);
                fs.WriteLine(Setting3.ToShortDateString());
                fs.Flush();
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, I'm actually working on an app for a LAN network, something basic, nothing big but I do need each instance of the program to read from one Settings file - I've searched all over the internet and found no good articles explaining how to create a Settings file and how to set it up in a single shared location.  Can you help with, perhaps a link?  Anything is appreciated

Comment: Sorry, looks like using the default setting file mechanism on a remote location (not in the .exe's directory), is a bit tricky and requires some code juggling.  It seemed easier to create your own strongly typed settings file.  I added some code for a simple app settings class that can be persisted to any file system location. This includes network paths or local file system paths.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for all your help, I was able to tweak this a bit and adjust it to my needs, much appreciated!